# Is CD polling from "SeaBIOS" after GRUB coming from VPS host (Vultr) or OS (Debian 10)?

Tags: vps, boot

I'm new to the VPS hosting scene and it's been a while since I installed Debian, 7-Wheezy was my last.

I'm seeing polling for a CD rom drive after GRUB from SeaBIOS (see first screenshot).

By "after GRUB" I mean, after the screen asking for you to select which OS to boot (see second screenshot).

Is this being done by Debian (10) or by the VPS hosting company (Vultr)?

The thing confusing me most is that it polls for CD after GRUB. I thought GRUB came after the BIOS. Maybe it's a VPS thing I'm not aware of.

I'd like to disable CD polling on boot, just not sure how to proceed.

[image: SeaBIOS shows after GRUB]

[image: GRUB is first]

Comment: The GRUB menu appears, asks which Debian kernel to boot, and then this screen appears, and then the OS continues to load from the Hard Disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SeaBios is from the VPS's back-end. It can appear otherwise because the GRUB menu appears over that message and it's revealed again after a kernel is chosen by GRUB.